# How to remove WARN message using Spring Cloud Sleuth and Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I need to log traces in the Netty logs, so I added this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SleuthGWConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HttpClientCustomizer customizer(HttpTracing httpTracing) {
        return (c) -> {
            return ReactorNettyHttpTracing.create(httpTracing).decorateHttpClient(c);


        };
    }
}
```

and the logs contain traces as expected:

```
[2m2022-05-18 18:16:16.306[0;39m [32mDEBUG [,,][0;39m [35m19820[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-2][0;39m [36mreactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [08685324-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59765] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@130d2eee
[2m2022-05-18 18:16:16.910[0;39m [32mDEBUG [,efbd8bcbe33f76e3,efbd8bcbe33f76e3][0;39m [35m19820[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-2][0;39m [36mr.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [1a19d87a-1, L:/127.0.0.1:59767 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8085] Handler is being applied: {uri=http://localhost:8085/get, method=GET}
[2m2022-05-18 18:16:16.936[0;39m [32mDEBUG [,efbd8bcbe33f76e3,761f2b4fd9a180ba][0;39m [35m19820[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-2][0;39m [36mr.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [1a19d87a-1, L:/127.0.0.1:59767 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8085] Received response (auto-read:false) : [Server=gunicorn/19.9.0, Date=Wed, 18 May 2022 16:16:16 GMT, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Type=application/json, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true, content-length=1382]
[2m2022-05-18 18:16:16.944[0;39m [32mDEBUG [,efbd8bcbe33f76e3,efbd8bcbe33f76e3][0;39m [35m19820[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-2][0;39m [36mr.n.http.client.HttpClientOperations    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [1a19d87a-1, L:/127.0.0.1:59767 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:8085] Received last HTTP packet
[2m2022-05-18 18:16:16.966[0;39m [32mDEBUG [,efbd8bcbe33f76e3,efbd8bcbe33f76e3][0;39m [35m19820[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-2][0;39m [36mr.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m [08685324-1, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59765] Last HTTP response frame
```

but a WARN message with **a big stack** trace appears at application start-up ([complete stack trace is here](https://github.com/taxone/sleuth-gateway-actuator/tree/main#readme)):

```
[36mo.s.c.s.a.i.w.SkipPatternConfiguration  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Most likely, there is an actuator endpoint that indirectly references an instrumented HTTP client. An exception was thrown during bean initialization. Will ignore that exception
```

After investigation, I found [the related issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/pull/1680). It seems that this does not cause real problems, but I'd like to know if it's possible creating a configuration which prevents the exception to be thrown at startup.

The sample project is [available here](https://github.com/taxone/sleuth-gateway-actuator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a property `logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.SkipPatternConfiguration=ERROR`. You can do it e.g. via `application.yml`

UPDATE:

With this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2166 we're lowering the noise by lowering the logging severity

Comment: My question is about how to prevent exception throwing, not to hide the warn message. If the message can be ignored, why is the log level set to WARN? It should be at DEBUG level.

Comment: I'm sorry - I misread what you want to achieve. The exception is being thrown because there is some mess with the bean creation. This seems like a bug - can you file it in Spring Cloud Sleuth and reference this SO question?

Comment: [Issue added](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/2166)

Comment: I've updated the answer - can we mark this as resolved?